# Resize UILabel font with one finger

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer

I would like to change a `UILabel` font size (and frame also) by clicking on the white dot (see image below) and using a pan gesture to do so. How can I do it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything and why didn't that work out for you?

Comment: I tried usin CGAffineTransformMakeScale but the label text rendering is not good when the scale value is too high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on same demo few months ago. I used https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView

It will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I tried this class and this is exactly what I was looking for. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving your feedback.